# Is it possible to implement custom UserDetailsServices to refresh the token?

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I am using Spring Security OAuth2 for authorizations. Here is my Oauth2 configuration:

```
@Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient(client)
                .secret(passwordEncoder().encode(secret))
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(timeout)
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("read", "write");
    }

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .tokenEnhancer(userTokenEnhancer)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .exceptionTranslator(new CustomOAuthExceptionTranslator());
    }
```

I accept three authorized grand types: `password`, `authorization_code`, `refresh_token` and I use the implemented custom version of UserDetailsService. I was wondering if it could be possible to implement the second version of UserDetailsService that could be the dedicated service when refreshing the token. How can I have both flows?